# How can I use oauth.create_client in different file than the one I called the constructor, in Authlib?

Tags: python, flask, authlib, flask-oauthlib

I need to connect to a website using Authlib. I am a newbie at this, so I studied some tutorials: [one](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/oauth1.html)., [two](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/flask.html), [three](https://github.com/authlib/demo-oauth-client/blob/master/flask-google-login/app.py) All of them gave the following structure:

1. create the `app` instance;
2. create the `oauth` instance, passing `app` to the `OAuth` constructor;
3. using `oauth` in the routing function decorators.

This structure is in the same file. The problem is that I need to use the `oauth` instance in a different file than the one the instance (point 3 from above) was created and I don't know how to do it. Some help is more than necessary.

Useful code:

*__init__py*:

```
from authlib.integrations.flask_client import OAuth
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates", static_folder="static")
app.config.from_object('config.Config')
oauth = OAuth(app)
oauth.register(name='Hattrick', client_id='...',
                       client_secret='...',
                       request_token_url='...',
                       request_token_params=None,
                       access_token_url='...',
                       access_token_params=None,
                       authorize_url='...', authorize_params=None,
                       api_base_url='...', client_kwargs=None)
```

*/index/index_routes.py*

```
@index_bp.route('/LoginToHattrick')
def LoginToHattrick():
    hattrick = oauth.create_client('Hattrick')
    return hattrick.authorize_redirect('...')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `oauth` definition to *index routes*:

```
@index_bp.route('/LoginToHattrick')
def LoginToHattrick():
    oauth = OAuth(wsgi.app)
    oauth.register(name='Hattrick', client_id='...',
                       client_secret='...',
                       request_token_url='...',
                       request_token_params=None,
                       access_token_url='...',
                       access_token_params=None,
                       authorize_url='...', authorize_params=None,
                       api_base_url='...', client_kwargs=None)
    hattrick = oauth.create_client('Hattrick')
    return hattrick.authorize_redirect('...')
```